# Java: Poker, deal a card

Tags: java

After I shuffle the cards in the deck `nextCard = deck.dealCard();` should draw the card on the top. The problem is that it shows all the time `"ACE of DIAMONDS"`(I think it is the first card when the deck is created) instead of the correct card and also my deck would still be the same size (52). But when I test with  `deck.dealCard();` it works just fine, my deck will go to 51 and the right card shows up. How can I fix `nextCard`?'

Shuffle and Fill the deck are both called in main and works just fine. (They are not the problem). When i  use only `deck.dealCard();` as already mentioned works just fine.

```
public class Game {
   Deck deck = new Deck();
   Pile pile = new Pile();

   Card nextCard;

   public void initNewGame(){
        //nextCard=null; //this don't help
        deck = new Deck();
        deck.fill();
        pile.clear();
   }     

    public Card pickNextCard(){
        nextCard = deck.dealCard();
        return nextCard;
    }
}
```

this is from Deck class:

```
public Deck(){
        theCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        fill();
    }
public Card dealCard(){
        return theCards.remove(0);
}
public void shuffleCards(){
        Collections.shuffle(theCards);
    }
public void fill(){
        theCards.clear();
        for(Suit suit : Suit.values()){
            for(Rank rank : Rank.values()){
                theCards.add(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
            }
        }
```

THIS IS MAIN:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Deck deck = new Deck();
       Pile pile = new Pile();
       Game game = new Game();
       deck.shuffleCards();

       System.out.println("\nLogic.CardNow: " + game.pickNextCard() +"\n");
}
```

Comment: Where's your shuffle happening?  We'd need to see that code.

Comment: I suppose the question is about `pickNextCard`, is that right? And where do you even call that method?

Comment: @GBlodgett yes I do everything else works fine

Comment: The code you posted still does not call `shuffleCards`. If you can't provide code which does what you describe, then we can't really help you.

Comment: @cHao I already said that everything works fine and the problem is nextCard, but I added the methods for you

Comment: Everything it's called in main, why should I post the tests?

Comment: @Zuzu: Again...where is the shuffle *happening*? I see nowhere in this code where you call `shuffleCards`.

Comment: @cHao why do you need the whole code? Everything happens in main why do you need that ?

Comment: Where do you shuffle? You're filling your cards with the same order every time, so it makes sense your first draw is always the same card...

Comment: @cHao I already said that it works just fine without nextCard ? the problem is not my shuffle

Comment: @Zuzu: Because i'm convinced, and it should be pretty obvious, that *not* everything is happening in main. If you always get the first card, then for some reason you're not shuffling.

Comment: @cHao I told you already everything is working fine and the shuffle aswell, if you do not see the problem and keep complaining about my shuffle

Comment: No it's not.  You've _defined_ the `shuffleCards` method, but you aren't calling it anywhere in the code you have posted, therefore the shuffle never _actually happens_.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Because I didn't post my main, how many times do I have to explain that ????? and why do you need to SEE it ?

Comment: Because we can't debug code we can't see.  It's up to you to post an [mcve] that demonstrates the whole problem.  Please review [ask].

Comment: @Zuzu: Because without it, the problem is not reproducible. The little bit of code you've posted should work fine, so the problem is somewhere in the pile of code you *haven't* posted.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I updated my code

Comment: @cHao Pile have nothing to do with my shuffle/ creation of the deck / drawing my card, also I have updated my main for you

Comment: So, yeah.  You're not calling the shuffle properly.  You're calling shuffle on the `deck` in `Main`, which is a completely different instance than the `deck` that is part of the `Game` class. So, no, your're not calling shuffle on the right deck.

Comment: You realize `deck.shuffleCards()` doesn't affect `game.deck`, right? (In fact, so far it looks like the `deck` and `pile` in `main` don't do anything at all.)

Comment: Basically, just have your Game shuffle its deck while it's init'ing, and at least some of your problems should go away. It won't resolve the "deck stays the same size" issue, but i'd wager that's due to asking `deck` about its size after telling `game` to deal a card. (That breaks for the same reason your shuffling does: the two decks are independent of each other.)

Comment: @cHao no problems are going away..

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you have two decks, not one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Deck deck = new Deck(); // deck 1
   Pile pile = new Pile(); 
   Game game = new Game(); // contains another deck, deck 2
   deck.shuffleCards(); // deck 1 is now shuffled

   System.out.println("\nLogic.CardNow: " + game.pickNextCard() +"\n"); // deck 2 (NOT SHUFFLED)
}
```

You need to either have `game` use your external (shuffled) deck, or you need to shuffle the deck that is inside of `game`.

The easiest option would be to update your `initGame` method to shuffle your deck:

```
public void initNewGame(){
    deck = new Deck();
    deck.fill();
    deck.shuffleCards(); // shuffle your deck
    pile.clear();
}
```